# How to display inline a select element after a div?

Tags: html, css

I have these HTML elements:

```
<div id="div1">
       <h2>Search what you want</h2>
      <input id="textSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search" />
</div>

<div id="div2">
<select id="droplist" class="form-control">
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I am trying to display them inline but I can't find the way to do it. I have searched on SO and applied some of the solutions, like involving both of the elements in a div (div1 and div2) and add in the CSS code something like this:

```
#div1, #div2
{
   display: inline;
}
```

I have also tried with inline-block and so many other solutions but none of them have worked. Is there a possible way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `h2` in `div1` inline too:

```
#div1, #div2, #div1 h2
{
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#div1, #div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or:

```
#div1, #div2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

As a side note, please, consider using class names for styling instead of id-s.

Comment: `float: left` is sufficient

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:
HTML:

```
<div id="disptable">
<div id="disptabcell">
       <span>Search what you want:</span>
      <input id="textSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
<div id="disptabcell">
<select id="droplist" class="form-control">
  <option>Option</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#disptable{display:table}
#disptabcell{display:table-cell}
span{font-size:18px;font-weight:bold}
```